# Detecting first button in layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I am trying to solve this conundrum: "How to get rest of the buttons in a list go under the first button."

In order to solve that issue, I have tried to set a boolean to detect the first button and apply the rule on anything below that, but button1 seems to go on top of button0 every time.

I listed the MainActivity below. The layout xml only has a Relative layout in it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
private ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
private boolean firstButton = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    categories.add(new Category("Mobility",CategoryTypes.MOBILITY));
    categories.add(new Category("Flexibility",CategoryTypes.FLEXIBILITY));
    categories.add(new Category("Mobility",CategoryTypes.MOBILITY));
    categories.add(new Category("Flexibility",CategoryTypes.FLEXIBILITY));
    categories.add(new Category("Mobility",CategoryTypes.MOBILITY));
    categories.add(new Category("Mobility",CategoryTypes.MOBILITY));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        makeButton(this, "Buttons"+i,i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
    {
        addButtonToLayout(buttons.get(i),relLayout,i);
        System.out.println(buttons.get(i).getLayoutParams());
    }
}

//This method constructs a button object, sets its text, id and an OnClickListener. Finally adds the buttons to buttons arraylist
void makeButton (Context context, String buttonText, int id)
{
    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setText(buttonText);
    button.setId(id);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons.add(button);
    System.out.println(button.getId());
}

//Method to add button to layout. The LayoutParams are used to add the rule that the buttons should be underneath each other.
void addButtonToLayout (Button button, RelativeLayout layout, int index)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsForSecondButton = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    if (firstButton)
    {
        firstButton = false;
        System.out.println(buttons.get(index).getText());
        //TODO: [BUG] Doesn't add the first button for some reason.
    }
    else if (!firstButton)
    {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, buttons.get(index-1).getId());
    }

    //paramsForSecondButton.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, buttons.get(0).getId());

    //params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, buttons.get(index).getId());
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
   // buttons.get(1).setLayoutParams(paramsForSecondButton);

    layout.addView(button);
}
```

Here is an image of the layout:
[image: image of layout]

Comment: why dont you add alignParentTop to your first button??. Why are you using relative layout if you need to show the buttons linearly. Use LinearLayout (Vertical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29267782/4584675) to similar question that should help you.

> The reason this is failing for you is because of the IDs you are using. Android uses "reserved" ids for things like the general content area of the app.
>
> Using your code, I was able to add 1000 to each ID and generate the intended result.

Also it is not a good idea to position your buttons in such way. Unless you have reasons for this a simle `LinearLayout` will do the job at half the price of computational time.

Comment: LinearLayout seemed to do the trick. Now I just have a problem of not being able to control the height anymore. I changed it to this: LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, R.dimen.default_button_height); and apparently it ignores any value I put in "default_button_height". (It is 30dp right now)

Comment: you set the height to `wrap_content` it is calculated automatically. Also have a look on [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), maybe it would serve you even better..

Comment: I agree, it should, but for some reason it fill the entire view with the two buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this condition have you tried:

```
if (firstButton)
{         
    firstButton = false;
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
}
else if (!firstButton)
{
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, buttons.get(index-1).getId());
}
```